# Proper size furnace filter?

Tags: hvac

I recently moved into a new house and found that the furnace didn't have a filter installed properly. Well, there was an old dirty one but it was just sitting upright against the right hand side of the duct so no air was going through it. It was also the wrong size (20x20) since it couldn't be laid down to actually filter the airflow.

I measured the dimensions of the duct connected to the furnace and it was a little over 16x20 (both sides a little bigger) so I bought a 16x20x4 but that doesn't really fit into this opening. I was able to jam it in but it still couldn't be laid flat.

Is it possible that this is a custom size? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

*(note: door removed for the pic, there is one normally)*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where does the filter go in that pic?  Did you need to undo screws to remove the filter "door"?  This looks "custom" in a bad way.

Comment: Usually the furnace should have a label saying what size filters for proper operation.

Comment: Perhaps there is a filter door on one of the other sides of the furnace but it was installed too close to a wall, so the ductwork was sliced open to provide a makeshift door?  Does air flow downwards through the duct in this photo?  Can you provide a more zoomed out picture and/or pictures of the other sides?

Comment: The door was on a metal plate which was screwed on. The door opens with latches so it definitely seems like it's meant for a filter. There's no other door. More pics: https://imgur.com/a/DeaCd9g

Comment: Looking at the hack job of the cutout, I would assume some DIY'er tried to put a filter in the wrong place.

Answer (score 6):

Looks to me like a 1" filter was intended, or maybe a 2".

Slide it in, then swing the bottom to the left, all the way across, so that it's in there at a diagonal. As long as the edges more or less fit the duct it doesn't really matter whether it's horizontal. In fact, some furnaces are designed with diagonal filter slots.

Either that or try a 14x20x1 (or x2). That's also a common size and may lay flat over the furnace port.

Comment: Is there a reason (other than it not fitting in the duct) that a 4" would not be intended? Like it would overload the furnace somehow?

Comment: generally a 4" filter has a specific housing unit the filter slides into since it can't be as easily rotated in place like a 1" filter

Comment: A furnace needs to expect a 4" filter due to the increased resistance. You should review the owners manual or post a model number so we can help.

Comment: @Dan when inserting the filter, be sure to note the airflow direction (usually printed on the side of the filter) and make sure the air will flow through the filter in the proper direction.

Comment: That furnace had better be configured for down flow or that's the wrong place for the filter. If air gets sucked in that hole then it's a down flow.